# Is Apache blocking I/O?

Tags: apache, unix, sockets

Is Apache blocking I/O or non-blocking IO?

Comment: If it would be blocking it wouldn't be able to handle thousands of connections at a time, something it is capable of. There might be a possible tuning but, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It forks a process for each connection, so it probably is blocking (unless it watches for timeout on the same thread as the socket i/o?).

To be sure you should probably look for socket creation calls in the source, and follow accesses to the socket descriptors... I'm not even sure if Apache has to do the forking mode, maybe it has an asynchronous mode too.

---

**Edit**

Right, there are a bunch of "[Multi-Processing Modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mpm.html)", which decide how to handle multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: Read the above comment - forking for each connection is unreasonable and not performance-wise saying the least.

Comment: @Poni True, looks like the modern options just let you specify a max number of threads (or children), each of which will do a certain amount of jobs asynchronously.

Comment: If it is non-blocking IO, what's the major difference of concurrency ability between apache and nginx?

Answer (score 3):

Apache supports both. default its blocking. there is non-blocking module using NIO events.
Its a performance based tuning to decide which method is to be used.

http://hc.apache.org/

For serving static contents its better to use non-blocking, but for use with a servlet container its better to use blocking[thread locals].

Comment: The OP’s question was ambiguous, but I would guess it concerns the well-known Apache HTTP Server (httpd) rather than Apache HttpComponents, a Java library.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is blocking i/o afaik. nginx uses an event based non blocking single thread and the memory usage is relatively much lower than apache. Apache uses one thread per connection and that is how it handles multiple connections.